# How to create service and use it in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I am having a simple login form and I want to validate user upon successful HTTP request and it works fine. however, I've written all the code in the controller itself and I don't want that. i am new to angularjs so i have trouble creating service. so I need to create service for my logic. can anyone create service for the logic in the controller so that code works exactly same? 
**sample.html**(for now it only prints username, password, and status code of response)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="mycontroller">
    Username <input type="text" ng-model="login" /><br><br> Password <input 
type="password" ng-model="pass" /><br>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="myfunc()">Login</button>
    <center>User name is {{ login }}, password is{{pass}}<br>
{{success.code}}
</div>
</body>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope, $http, $log) {
$scope.login = "";
$scope.pass = "";
$scope.myfunc = function() {
    var obj = {
        login_id: $scope.login,
        password: $scope.pass
    }
    var mydata = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://myapiurl.com/signin/",
        headers: {
            "authorization": "oauth mytoken",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        data: mydata
    }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            $scope.success = response.data;
        },
        function(reason) {
            $scope.error = reason.data
            console.log(reason);
            $log.info(reason.data);
        });
}
});
```

Comment: you just need to return a Promise, which $http already does: `return $http(...).then((res)=>{return res.data});`. Wrap it all in a function with parameters and send it back to the controller (_once injected_) : `YourService.myfunc($scope.login,$scope.pass).then((data)=>{$scope.success=data;})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `myService` factory and create a function to send http req and return the response.

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {

    return {
        httpReq: function(data) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://myapiurl.com/signin/",
                headers: {
                    "authorization": "oauth mytoken",
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                },
                data: data
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Now call it from the controller.

```
app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope, myService, $log) {
    $scope.login = "";
    $scope.pass = "";
    $scope.myfunc = function() {
        var obj = {
            login_id: $scope.login,
            password: $scope.pass
        }
        var mydata = JSON.stringify(obj);
        myService.httpReq(mydata)
            .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    $scope.success = response.data;
                },
                function(reason) {
                    $scope.error = reason.data
                    console.log(reason);
                    $log.info(reason.data);
                });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Super simple. First create a service, which injects `$http` module. Make a method you can call which returns promise from the `$http` module. In this example it's a `get` method.

```
app.service("ExampleService", function($http){

    this.ExampleRequest = function(){
       return $http.get('url');
    }

});
```

Inject the service created above and you can call the functions you've defined in the service. Notice that the `.then` comes from the promise.

```
app.controller("exampleCtrl", function($scope, ExampleService){

    $scope.onClick = function(){
       ExampleService.ExampleRequest().then(function(data){
        //  Do something with data
       });
    }

});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `ExampleService.ExampleRequest()`, since you are calling a function?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Good spot. Thanks